# How do I check the consistency of checkout files?

Tags: git

`git fsck` only checks the database.
`git status` only stats files.

After a bad system crash and a lenghty `fsck`, how can I have git check the checkout files' consistency ?

Answer (score 1):

Let me try rephrasing this to be more precise, because one way, the answer is "you can't" and the other is that you can (and I can answer that one).

The setup is that something has damaged some file(s) on the system, but that you have a repository that passes `git fsck`, so you think *the repository itself* is all OK.  That repository has a work-tree; the work-tree has files in it.  How can you use Git to tell if all the files are undamaged?

The answer is that you can't, because not all work-tree files correspond to files that are versioned inside the repository.  Moreover, there's no requirement that work-tree files retain the same form outside the repository that they have inside it or would have if you ran `git checkout` on the `HEAD` commit.

On the other hand, you might want to compare those files that *do* have committed versions, to their committed versions, to see if they match, and if not, to examine them in more detail.  The concern here is that while `git status` *seems* to do that, we know (from examining the Git source perhaps) that `git status` first calls `lstat` on each file, then compares the stat results to cached data in the index file in `.git/index`.  If the stat results match the index file, Git assumes that the data inside the file are correct—but because the system itself was damaged, we're concerned that the internal data may be corrupted even though the `stat` result is unchanged from earlier.

The solution to this problem is simple enough: remove the index file entirely.<sup>1</sup>  Then run `git reset`, which re-builds the index.  Since there is literally no cached `lstat` data any more (we removed, or at least moved, the old index), Git must rebuild everything.

Now `git status`'s output is believable: it's really comparing the work-tree to the (new) index, after filling in the (new) index from the `HEAD` commit.

(At this point, if you had saved the old index, you can now put it back, and re-enable automatic `git gc` if you disabled it.)

---

<sup>1</sup>If you trust the index contents—it has its own internal SHA-1 hash check, so it's probably good, and it might have some value, i.e., `git add`-ed files that now have hash IDs in the repository—you can just `mv` it out of the way temporarily, then `mv` it back later.  You may wish to disable automatic `git gc` for the duration as well, although as long as you run only `git reset` and `git status`, that should be unnecessary.

---

Note that there is an alternative method that's less Git-dependent: just re-check-out the same commit and compare trees directly with ordinary file system tools (e.g., `cmp` each file).  You can do this very simply by just cloning the repository locally.